# Laravel 8 sum data on condition hasMany

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I always get error :

> Property [payment] does not exist on this collection instance.

But i already set eloquent on `User` :

```
public function payment() { return $this->hasMany(Payment::class); }
```

Its not working when im use `where` and `whereBetween`.
its sound good if i do like this :

```
User::first()->payment->sum('amount')
```

Example on tinker :

```
$l = User::whereBetween('created_at', ['2022-02-20', '2022-02-28'])->with('payment')->get()
$l->payment->sum('amount')
```

I need result only 1 row not in array. because im find grand total for table footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$l = User::whereBetween('created_at', ['2022-02-20', '2022-02-28'])->with('payment')->get();

$grandTotal = $l->map(function ($item) {
    $item->total_amount = $item->payment->sum('amount');
    return $item;
})->sum('total_amount');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditions to a relationship in the way mentioned below

```
$users = User::whereBetween('created_at', [
         '2022-02-20', '2022-02-28'
     ])->with(['payments'])
     ->get();
```

as you're fetching multiple users you need to iterate through the loop. That is what you were missing in your code

```
$users = $users->map(function ($user) {
            $user['total_payment'] = $user->payments->sum('amount');
            return $user;
        });
```

and then

```
$grandTotal = $users->sum('total_payment');
```

Comment: hi,, thank u for answer.. btw field created_at is on User,, not in payment,, can u edit it and add sum

Comment: it same like im doing before.. im use it for tbody.. but i need grand total for tfooter.. it should be only 1 row for result.. not in array.

Comment: for a grand total you have to map a collection. as there will be multiple users and you want a sum of nested relationship

Comment: yes.. thank you sir.. im still new in laravel :D

Comment: Updated an answer